# Is there any compiler/interpreter to execute code for php 5.3?

Tags: php-5.3

Is there any online complier/interpreter to execute code for php 5.3?

like there is one for php http://codepad.org/

But it does not support php 5.3 features.

Can any one help, in this?

Comment: I got something but not for php 5.3 http://www.ideone.com

Comment: [Codepad](http://codepad.org/) is also < 5.3 =(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The updated answer as of today is http://codepad.viper-7.com/

Answer (score 1):

It would be easy to make one yourself, simply make a form and get it to eval() the input. You will need a server with PHP 5.3 on it, also make sure you secure the form so people don't wreck your server.

Comment: Thanks for reply cobby. But I don't have any online server on which I can install php 5.3 and show the code and its output to others. That is why I want if any existing one available. But thanks for your help